# how do I make a text file line into a list

Tags: c#, class, streamwriter

is it possible to make this into a list and then make a code where I can delete what's inside the list per line (text file) and then searching the contents of the list

```
class data
    {
        public void addData(string user_name, string user_email, string user_gender, string user_contact)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("data.txt", true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(user_name + " | " + user_email + " | " + user_gender + " | " + user_contact);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: lines of the text file]

Comment: Yes, it is possible to make a list and to perform logic.  What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?

Comment: @David It's just that I can't figure it out how to make a list in c#

Comment: [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) is often a good place to start.  You can also use your favorite search engine to look for things like "C# list example".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible! And Microsoft write some really nice documentation for you to learn about it [right here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=net-6.0#system-io-file-readlines(system-string)). Here's a simple little program to read the file into a list.

```
const string file = "{insert your path here}/data.txt";

var stringList = File.ReadLines(file).ToList();

foreach (var line in stringList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

There's a nice example on the documentation I've linked that shows you how to lookup things on that list so I'll leave the next part for you to work out